What does the addToCart callback function look like for Live Search?
We are working toward enabling the Live Search Product Listing Page Widget on our Web site. I am trying to add a callback function to the storeDetails const in dev-template.html. What should it look like?
/storefront-product-listing-page-main/dev-template.html
<script type="text/javascript">
const root = document.querySelector('div.search-plp-root');
const storeDetails = {
  environmentId: 'xxxxx',
  websiteCode: 'xxxxxxx',
  storeCode: 'main_website_store',
  storeViewCode: 'default',
  config: {
    minQueryLength: '2',
    pageSize: 8,
    perPageConfig: {
      pageSizeOptions: '12,24,36',
      defaultPageSizeOption: '24',
    },
    currencySymbol: '$',
    currencyRate: '1',
    displaySearchBox: true, // display search box
    displayOutOfStock: true,
    allowAllProducts: false,
    addToCart: (sku, options, quantity)=>{console.log("hi" + sku + 'op' + options + 'qty' + quantity)},
  },
  context: {
    customerGroup: 'General',
  },
  apiKey: 'search_gql',
  environmentType: 'Testing',
};
</script>

When I push this up to my Staging site, I am not getting my message written to console. I don't know if I've written the function wrong or if it's in the wrong place or what ...
Ultimately, we'd like to add a function that will trigger and send data to GTM. I am aware that it is currently a limitation of Live Search.


I figured out how/where to add a callback function when the “Add to Cart” is clicked on the PLP and search results pages.
Copy these two files into the design/frontend folder:

vendor/magento/module-live-search-product-listing/view/frontend/templates/category_product_listing.phtml

vendor/magento/module-live-search-product-listing/view/frontend/templates/product_listing.phtml


The file path would look like:

app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_LiveSearchProductListing/templates/category_product_listing.phtml

app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_LiveSearchProductListing/templates/product_listing.phtml


And add the addToCart function in both files:
window.LiveSearchPLP({storeDetails: {
  config: {
    addToCart: ((sku, options, quantity)=>{console.log("pl" + sku)}),
  }
}


Adding a caveat: I did not notice this yesterday, but this appears to completely prevent a product from getting added to the cart. So while it works, it does break needed functionality.
